When are altcoins offtopic and when not offtopic?

When should a question be considered offtopic related to altcoins? And are there any rules for answers that mention specific altcoins when it can be avoided or not mentioned in the question or considered controversial/unethical/scam?

Are the rules same for everyone including moderators?

If we are allowed to mention specific "altcoins" on "bitcoin" Stackexchange how do we decide which altcoins are good enough to be mentioned?


My questions are related to this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/102275/


When should a question be considered offtopic related to altcoins? And are there any rules for answers that mention specific altcoins when it can be avoided or not mentioned in the question or considered controversial/unethical/scam?

The word "altcoin" is not outright banned (nor should it be) and questions and answers may mention altcoins if the question/answer is generic enough to be applicable to Bitcoin. Questions and answers are not removed for simply mentioning or discussing altcoins. They are only removed if they are only applicable to altcoins and not related to Bitcoin at all.
There are a few meta questions about this site's scope. The most relevant is probably the proposal to change the scope to just Bitcoin. You may be able to find better and more complete guidance through there and the linked discussions.

Are the rules same for everyone including moderators?

Yes. Are there any instances where you think that a moderator's question/answer was not deleted but a similar one from a normal user was?

If we are allowed to mention specific "altcoins" on "bitcoin" Stackexchange how do we decide which altcoins are good enough to be mentioned?

IMO any altcoins can be mentioned so long as it is relevant to the question and the question is also relevant to Bitcoin in some way.
For example, if there were a question about why Bitcoin doesn't implement a feature in that is present in altcoin X, I think it is perfectly reasonable to have such a question on this site and for altcoin X to be named in the question and answer. Such a question is relevant to Bitcoin and the altcoin is relevant to the question and answer.


In the proposal that you shared, your answer mentioned using altcoins when it's about a concept and not specific coin. I agree with that approach. 2. No I never had any issues with removal of question or answer related to altcoins. I wanted to make sure I know if it works same for everyone. I respect all mods for their contribution in bitcoin and stackexchange and would have replied or edited the answer itself if it was done by a new user. There have been few answers by new accounts to shill their altcoins.



Agree if a question has an altcoin mentioned and involves comparison with bitcoin, it should be mentioned. Also it's good to answer such questions many times to avoid confusion or debunk things spread by marketing teams of altcoins.


I have few things to add: A Imagine a newbie searches something about bitcoin on Google, gets few results from Bitcoin SE, reads few names of other altcoins in some answers by users with good reputation. Assumes things. Is this good or bad? B Vitalik is proud to make premines legitimate with his altcoin. Are we helping people like him unknowingly in some Q&A? C Bitcoin SE should help devs & users interested in Bitcoin and looks better than few others. Can we improve it and get more devs interested to build bitcoin projects?

D Some of the questions and answers from Bitcoin SE are used as reference on other platforms in lot of discussions.
